# stackedbarchart in javafx to show values when in iteration

Tags: java, if-statement, javafx, commit

so i create 3 lists A,B,C

list A could take the values in { RED, GREEN , BLUE}

list B could take in the values in { MAN , WOMAN , GIRL, BOY }

list c could take any values between 0-100

The inputs could be

RED WOMAN 55

BLUE GIRL 32

RED BOY 89

the number of inputs are random meaning that user could give 4 or 6 inputs

now what i want to do is to construct a stackedbarchart with series as RED, BLUE, GREEN,

Q.>how do i go about??

```
 Iterator iterator1=lista.iterator();
 Iterator iterator2=listb.iterator();
 Iterator iterator3=listc.iterator();

 while(iterator1.hasNext())
 {
 String ah=iterator1.next();
 String bh=iterator2.next();
 String ch=iterator3.next();


if(ah=="RED")
 {
    Redseries.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>(bh,ch));
  }

if(ah=="GREEN")
 {
    Greenseries.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>(bh,ch));
  }

 if(ah=="BLUE")
 {
    Blueseries.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>(bh,ch));
  }
 }
 Scene scene = new Scene(sbc, 800, 600);
    sbc.getData().addAll(Redseries,Greenseries,Blueseries);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
```

now here is the most annoying part,
there is no error but as the addition to the series is implemented in the if loop, the changes made to the series are not committed, so although i can see the graph with nice xaxis and yaxis i can't see the bars.

please help,

thanks

Comment: `if(ah=="RED")`  (╯︵╰,)

Comment: @MarounMaroun that is not a problem i can use equals...